# Getting Values from a Hashmap in a different class

Tags: java, selenium, hashmap

I have written a piece of code to put locators to be used in my selenium scipt in a hashmap have also written an entryset there to get the values from the map.

```
public class ReadDatafromExcel {

    @Test
    public void putIntoHashmap() throws IOException     
    {

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/suvin/Documents/SeleniumWebdriver/Script/PaytmAutomationFramework/src/testUtilities/TestData.xlsx");

            XSSFWorkbook workbook= new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

            XSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowiterator = firstSheet.iterator();

            HashMap<String,String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
            String key= null;
            String value= null;

            while (rowiterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = rowiterator.next();

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                int i;  
                for (i=0;i<=1;i++)
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    if(i==0)
                    { 
                        key =cell.getStringCellValue();
                    }
                    if(i==1)
                    {
                        value=cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                    }

                }
                map.put(key, value);    
            }

           // String Retrieved_value= map.get("Test11");
          //  System.out.println(Retrieved_value);

            Set set= (Set)map.entrySet();
            Iterator itr= set.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                Map.Entry entry= (Entry)itr.next();    
                System.out.println(entry.getKey()+":"+entry.getValue());

            }

        }
}
```

Now I want to use this hasmap in a different class. I created an object rd  of the ReadDatafromExcel class like this in the new class

```
public class ccTransactions {

    public ReadDatafromExcel rd = new ReadDatafromExcel();
```

}

I want to use the values of the hasmap created in ReadDatafromExcel in this class . How can I do it?

something like

```
driver.findelement(By.Xpath(USE VALUE FROM HASHMAP)).sendkeys();
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `map` to be a field of the class `ReadDatafromExcel`
like `private HashMap<String,String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();`
and remove it from the method `putIntoHashmap()` then add another method

```
public String getValue(String key){
return map.get(key);
}
```

then you can use it as `rd.get(key);`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It really help. However now when I am entering the numeric value to be read from the excel I am getting an error message "Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell". How can I modify the above code to handle this?

Comment: Then use nextRow.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue(); instead of nextRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method as follows:

```
   public Map<String, String> putIntoHashmap(String filePath) throws IOException 

    {

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);

            XSSFWorkbook workbook= new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

            XSSFSheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowiterator = firstSheet.iterator();

            HashMap<String,String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
            String key= null;
            String value= null;

            while (rowiterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = rowiterator.next();

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                key = nextRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                value = nextRow.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

                map.put(key, value);    
            }

         return map;
    }
```

Now, call the method after creating an object of your class like:

```
ReadDatafromExcel rd = new ReadDatafromExcel();
Map<String, String> data = rd.putIntoHashmap("Path to your excel file");
```

And then, use the data from your test methods:

```
driver.findelement(By.Xpath(data.get("**your desired key**"))).sendkeys();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It really help. However now when I am entering the numeric value to be read from the excel I am getting an error message "Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell". How can I modify the above code to handle this?